# New Document Content Types

Tags: content-type

When the template is uploaded for a new content type is automatically applies that template to all content types. Also, the default blank document option is also over written.

How can the new blank document be reverted to it's default behavior and each new content type be assigned individual template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define multiple document templates you have to implement multiple content types.

I assume that you want keep the New Document which comes OOTB and additionally your custom document template. If yes, then you should create a separate content type (inherited from Document content type) in which your custom columns should be added and in the `Advanced Settings` upload your document template file.

Now in the document library, enable the `Allow management of content types?` from the `Advanced Settings` in document library.

To manage the order of templates in the New Document option you can specify the order of content type from `Change new button order and default content type` link. Please make sure that the default `Document` (which will be by default added when you enable the content type for that library) content type is added in the document library.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

users1100 answer is correct. Just want to reffer a [good series of blog posts about SharePoint document management](http://blog.enovapoint.com/post/Sharepoint-Document-Management-Doing-it-Right), starting from creation of content types, which will be helpfull for you to know not only how to do it but and why it is important to do in this way.